# Query all Sharepoint workflows for their internal status

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I'm trying to get the internal status of all sharepoint workflows.

Is there anyway to programmatically query for all workflows, and get their status? Either through a CAML query or the the object model?

I realize that I can iterate over all items in sharepoint, and see if there is a workflow attached, and then get the status. However, that is overkill, as there are 100,000s of items, and only a small subset have workflows. I want to run a periodic report to fetch the status of all workflows, without bringing the server to it's knees.

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: After running a Workflow on an item, ever notice any new columns? :-) You may have to alter the view.

Comment: hmm...that really doesn't help me. That is in the gui. I need to do something programatically, where I can query all workflows, and determine their status. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view is, at its heart, a CAML query. The comment from @pst is a good choice if you don't want to iterate through all the items; just swipe the CAML from the view definition of any view that shows the workflow status column. The Lists.asmx Web service could come in handy here, though I usually use PowerShell on the server to extract view definitions.

If you do iterate through the items in the object model, here's a snippet to get rolling:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(url))
using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    var manager = site.WorkflowManager;
    var list = web.Lists[listname];
    if (list == null || list.Hidden)
    {
        return "Cannot work under these conditions.";
    }

    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
    {
        foreach (SPWorkflow workflow in item.Workflows)
        {
            if ((workflow.InternalState & SPWorkflowState.Faulting) == SPWorkflowState.Faulting)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(SPWorkflowState.Faulting.ToString());
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `SPSite.WorkflowManager`. This will let you examine workflow definitions and running instances across an entire site collection. The `CountWorkflows` method is probably what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.workflowmanager.aspx

-Oisin